# Backbone.js routing

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have  html code as follows

```
<a href="#users/<%= id %>/History">hello</a>
```

In Backbone my route is as follows

```
"users/:id/History": "historyPage",
```

However the function is never called when i click on the link and I keep getting error loading page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start up the History system with Backbone.history.start()?

Comment: In that case I'd need to see more of your code to try and see if I could tell what's going wrong. Any chance you could make a jsFiddle for just the routing problem?

Comment: I have also removed jquery mobile routing capabilties as desribed in this article. http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 1):

Change `href="#users/<%= id %>/History"` to `href="#/users/<%= id %>/History"` (i.e. add `/` after `#`)
http://jsfiddle.net/GX8WJ/3/

Comment: tried doing it still says error loading page. Does it make a difference that i am using phone gap ? Do i have to specify the root of the website differently ?

Comment: @VBK wow! i've just updated my opera to the latest version and guess what? the jsfiddle doesn't work. i have no idea why. yesterday everything works as expected. i mean, `historyPage` callback is called. well, honestly i didn't use phonegap, so i don't know if there is any differences between using backbone.js w/ phonegap or w/o it. but i suppose not. btw, have you seen this example of using backbone.js together with phonegap: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-mobile-app-with-backbone-js-and-phonegap/

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. And if it's not too much trouble could you tell me what was wrong with your code?

Comment: In that article it asks you to disable routing for jqm. I was including that portion of the code in the wrong place. It needed to be included before the jquery mobile javascript. I am now having css problems with my list view :(. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11118017/770874. It would be awesome if you could help me out.